# Easiest Way to Pass Variable to New Form in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5

I was wondering what is the easiest way to pass a variable to a new form that appears after a button click. Here is my code:

```
public void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ID;
        string Error;
        Error = "Please enter a valid ID, then submit.";
        ID = Identification.Text;
        if (ID.Length != 5)
        {
            Identification.Text = " ";
            Identification.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show(Error);
        }
        else
        {
            Identification.Text = " ";
            Identification.Focus();
            DetailForm Detail = new DetailForm();
            Detail.Show();
        }
    }
```

In DetailForm, I want to use the string "ID", which is entered in the textbox "Identification" on Form1 for some other purposes but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that without completely changing my code. This is probably a simple task for anyone familiar with C# but I'm still pretty new to the language so I'm struggling with it. Thanks!

Comment: Add the variable in DetailForm's Constuctor, and then you can passi the ID

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want your `DetailForm` to get your `string ID`. To do that, I would define `ID` as a property in the `DetailForm` class and then add an `id` argument to `DetailForm`'s constructor.

```
class DetailForm : Form
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    // ... other fields/properties

    public DetailForm(int id) : base()
    {
        ID = id;
    }
    // ... other methods
}
```

Then, in your `Send_Click` event handler, you can create your `DetailForm` like this:

```
DetailForm detail = new DetailForm(ID);
```

And then open it normally, with `detail.Show();`.

Comment: Why make it a public property? It could be a private field.

Comment: @DavidArno Doesn't really matter, but I did it in case the ID is changed by the `DetailForm` and the updated ID needs to be retrieved by the original form. However, if that doesn't need to happen, then you're right, a private field would be better.